# Data type for indexPath.row

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, nsindexpath

Here's my code

```
NSInteger selectedRow = selectedStationPath.row;
            UITableViewCell *cellz = [tabView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedRow inSection:0]];
            UIColor *color = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.0 green:0.5 blue:1.0 alpha:0.2];
            cellz.contentView.backgroundColor=color;
            NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",selectedRow]);
```

`selectedStationPath` is a global `NSIndexPath`... If I put a number instead of `selectedRow` into `indexPathForRow` it works.  NSLog prints `selectedRow` properly, however when I put `selectedRow` into `indexPathForRow`, it doesn't work even though NSLog is printing the `selectedRow`...

Comment: can you log value of selectedRow?

Comment: Yes the value prints the proper row.

Comment: It works now... it seems as though I first have to deselect the row first otherwise it doesnt work.... its odd, but now it works...

Comment: how you are setting value in selectedStationPath???

Comment: selectedStationPath is inside didSelectRow of tabView